# How to use map in XIB or a project that doesn't contain storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mapkit, xib

I am trying to add map in my Application where I can add `Latitude` & `Longitude` and get some location on map.

1. I have added a MapView to my XIB
2. Make a connection / IBOutlet

`@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;`

3. Added Mapkit Framework
4. Add Delegate MKMapViewDelegate

where in VIEWDIDLOAD

```
self.mapView.delegate = self;


    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(initializeMap) withObject:self waitUntilDone:YES];


   [mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
```

Which calls this Method

```
-(void)initializeMap {

    mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] init];

}
```

But Whenever I run the Application everytime it crash and gives the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: ' initWithCoder:: MKMapView must be initialized on the main thread.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '<MKMapView: 0xb1b35c0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); transform = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; alpha = 0; opaque = NO; layer = (null)> initWithCoder:: MKMapView must be initialized on the main thread.'

Comment: You already create your map view as IBOutlet. Why are you allocating it again?

Comment: just tried a possibility.

Comment: Don't do it. It is wrong.

Comment: @UlasSancak yes you are right whats the right way?

Comment: If the outlet is connected, you needn't allocate  / initialize again. You can use self.mapView and work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be correct, you can try following points:-

1) Try to load your map on separate view controller.

2) Load map on main thread.

3) Make sure you have added `MapKit.framework` framework.

4) While loading map make sure there is not too much processing on the view.

Hope this will help you to resolve your issue :)

Comment: yes loading on a Separate VC resolves the issue. What could be the reason, I was loading trying to view map with someother details.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong about it, your steps look correct.

1. Add a MapView to your xib with IB
2. Create an IBOutlet on your class and link it to the MapView on the xib
3. Go to `Build Phases` and link with `MapKit.framework`
4. Add `#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>` to your class

I'm attaching a project for reference
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2175823/MapTest.zip

Do it again from scratch, check your steps one by one, post more info if you can't solve.

ps: Your error suggests that you are playing with background threads and UI (you shouldn't, UI must be changed only in the main thread), are you doing something fancy?

Comment: look at the attached project, try again.

Comment: I have some other details that are to be shown on this current UI coming from web-service response, As i get them I pass them to the next screen thats it. And on this VC I have just added this Map trying to get the location on the basis of lat-long coming from that response.

Comment: Ok, I demonstrated you with a sample project that they are the correct steps. If you need more assistance, you need to post more details of what you are doing, because the problem that you are seeing is generated by something else that you are doing.